# Deleting system apps on a rooted phone

Tags: custom-roms

I have a rooted phone that I only want to use as a phone.  In other words, I do not want my children to have access to any other apps.  I can use an app blocker, but this phone only has a small capacity (Samsung Galaxy Young), so I cannot afford to load too much control software.  It would be better to remove as much as possible to make room, otherwise the phone tends to grind to a halt.  How do I know which preloaded apps I can safely delete without affecting the working of the phone?

Comment: May be helpful: [I have less than 40 apps (including system apps); What else can I remove?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/65666) Also see: [Remove bloatware on Galaxy S2 - what are my options?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/30162)

Comment: Titanium backup does a good job with removing system apps. It is safe with Google apps, and possibly like gallery, or internet. Some apps have a freeze function to test if you can remove. Also, non root users can disable system apps. So disabled apps should be safe to remove. Be sure to backup anyway though

Comment: @TheBro21 Could you add this as an answer please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove bloatware on Galaxy S2 - what are my options?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30155/remove-bloatware-on-galaxy-s2-what-are-my-options)

Answer (score 1):

Titanium backup generally does a good job with removing system apps. It is safe with Google apps, and possibly with apps like gallery, or internet. Titanium however does offer you to uninstall core apps too, which could be potentially dangerous.

Some apps (like titanium. However unfortunately only pro) have a freeze function to test if you can remove. Also, non root users can disable system apps. So disabled apps should be safe to remove. Be sure to backup anyway though