# Which Apps can be deleted from an Android?

Tags: system-apps

Are there any pre-loaded apps that can be deleted without affecting the operation of the phone, or of other apps? The purpose is for ease of use, and to save space.

Hi, thank you. I have a Wiko 2 phone, an Android version 9, U307AS with 16 GB for data. I have 64 apps.  76% of memory is already used. There are apps I never use, and apps where I have two for the same purpose. I rather have just the ones I need and use including some new ones. Please let me know if you need more information.  Thank you.

Comment: Depends entirely on the phone and Android version you are using. Until you tell us both we cannot provide you a precise advice. In addition, see if this helps: [I have less than 40 apps (including system apps); What else can I remove?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65666/i-have-less-than-40-apps-including-system-apps-what-else-can-i-remove)

Comment: Additionally the manufacturer (and it's modifications made to Android) plus the device hardware have an impact on the pre-installed apps Especially hardware (Qualcom, Mediatek, ..) related apps are usually those you should never disable, otherwise the device may end up in a boot-loop.